# 404 Not Found (The resource could not be found) - Trouble with GAE and Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, jinja2

I am new to Python, GAE and the datastore model. So there are lots of things which I do not know yet, so please be patient :)

I am working on a web service that allows people to post 'name' and 'desc' (description) of an  item and it will be included in a table on the same page. However when I clicked the submit button I got the error: 404 Not Found, The resource could not be found.

I am expecting a lot of things to be wrong in my code shown below (I only include short snippets of my code which I think is relevant to make it easier for reading), and my biggest problem is I have no idea which parts are wrong or which specific questions to ask. But I hope I can use this chance to learn more about everything that's involved in my code (Jinja, HTML, GQL etc), and how I can fit them all together.

```
    class Events(ndb.Model):
        name = ndb.StringProperty()
        desc = ndb.StringProperty()

    class Promote(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            query = ndb.gql("SELECT * "
                            "FROM Events "
                            )
            template_values = {"events" : query,}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('promote.htm')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

        def post(self):
            event = Events(name = self.request.get('name'), desc = self.request.get('desc'))
            event.put()
            self.redirect('/promote')


    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Main),
                                   ('/publicsearch', PublicSearch),
                                   ('/promote', Promote)],
                                  debug=True)
```

This is my html code for that page.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class = "container">
   <form action="/promote" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <p> Promote your event here! </p>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <p> Name of event: <br>
                        <textarea class="input-block-level" name="name" rows="1" cols = "50"> </textarea></p>
                    <p> Event description: <br>
                        <textarea class="input-block-level" name="desc" rows="3" cols = "50"> </textarea></p>

                        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <h4> Events feed </h4>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="30%">Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for event in events %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ event.name }} </td>
                <td>{{ event.desc }}  </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should try and frame your questions so that only one question is being asked.  If you want general code review there are other stackexchange places for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is trying to post to a handler with a url of `/wishlist` however the only handler for POST methods you have registered is for `/promote`.

These things need to match up.  Either change the form or the handler mapping.

Also while you are at it check that your `app.yaml` makes sense. Have a look in the logs whilst you are at it, you will see what URL is being requested.

Comment: Ah thanks! I was careless. I have just changed the form to post to /promote. The data entered is also successfully stored into the datastore. But now when I clicked on the 'submit' button it leads to a blank page?

Comment: You now need to do some debugging.  Add some logging in your get method for promote handler and see what is going on. Check that the redirect is working etc.....